# What is the difference between a workflow and a user flow?

Tags: workflow, task-flow

I am new to UX just graduated and I was asked to do a design challenge about service accessibility.

They provided assets, personas and a use case scenario. The main problem is to find ways to the user reschedule medical appointments via a mobile app.

However, they asked me to do a workflow which is not a term that I am familiar with…just wondering if I should ping them back asking if they meant user flow?

Comment: Depends on the context but yes, I would read that as the same thing.

Comment: It's probably best to ask for clarification. Or, if you want to not sound uninformed, confirm that they're looking for a thing that you know as a user flow.

Comment: Thanks! I will ask for clarification, I know that UX team is new, so they might call user flow as a workflow in my view.

Comment: Actually, the workflow was the design process in general.